How to prevent converting to UTC in the dayjs plugin?
There is a code:
import * as dayjs from 'dayjs';
import * as utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';
import * as timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone';
dayjs.extend(utc);
dayjs.extend(timezone);

//...

console.log('date', date, typeof date);
const myDate = dayjs(date);
console.log('time', myDate.format('HH:mm'));

Output:
date 2024-06-17T02:15:00+02:00 string
time 00:15



dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_utc);
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_timezone);

const date = '2024-06-17T02:15:00+02:00';

console.log('date', date, typeof date);
const myDate = dayjs(date);
console.log('time', myDate.format('HH:mm'));
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/utc.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/timezone.js"></script>



But I need 02:15 instead of it's UTC version.
I tried 13-15 different ways, but I always get the result in UTC. So please check your answer before providing it.
dayjs.tz(date, dayjs.tz.guess())
dayjs(date).tz(dayjs.tz.guess(), true)
dayjs(date).tz(dayjs(date).format('Z'))
dayjs(date, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ')
// etc


When I run the code I see the time in my local timezone (10:15). What is your PC timezone set to?

If you want to display the time using the offset provided in the ISO 8601 string, you'll probably need to parse that out first and use it with the timezone plugin or similar

It doesn't matter what time zone I have on my PC. The time zone is set in the input text string. And I can't get dayjs to accept it and work with it instead of UTC.
